# Find component in SAP GUI using VBA

Tags: vba, sap-gui

I'm trying to solve a relatively straight forward problem. I would like to be able to use excel VBA to find a component in the SAP GUI window.

The Script can be found below:

```
If Not IsObject(application) Then
 Set SapGuiAuto  = GetObject("SAPGUI")
 Set application = SapGuiAuto.GetScriptingEngine
End If
If Not IsObject(connection) Then
   Set connection = application.Children(0)
End If
If Not IsObject(session) Then
   Set session    = connection.Children(0)
End If
If IsObject(WScript) Then
   WScript.ConnectObject session,     "on"
   WScript.ConnectObject application, "on"
End If
session.findById("wnd[0]").maximize
session.findById("wnd[0]/tbar[1]/btn[42]").press
session.findById("wnd[1]/usr/txtSEARCH_BY-MATNR").text = "53211"
session.findById("wnd[1]/usr/txtSEARCH_BY-MATNR").caretPosition = 5
session.findById("wnd[1]/tbar[0]/btn[0]").press
```

The Code can be found below:

```
      More Scripting here
    -----------------------------------------------
    For Each row In [Multi_Lvl_BOM].Rows

        If (Cells(Row_Num, 1).Value = "") Then
            Exit For
        End If

        If (row.Columns(9).Value = "N/A") Then GoTo NextIteration2b

        session.findById("wnd[0]/tbar[1]/btn[42]").press
        -----------------------------------------------------------
            Everything works fine until here

        session.findById("wnd[1]/usr/txtSEARCH_BY-MATNR").text = "53211"
        -----------------------------------------------------------
            On that line Excel Throws an Error

        session.findById("wnd[1]/usr/txtSEARCH_BY-MATNR").caretPosition = 5
        session.findById("wnd[1]/tbar[0]/btn[0]").press

    NextIteration2b:
    Row_Num = Row_Num + 1

Next
```

I recorded a script in SAP, and when I run it there, it works fine. However, when I try to use it in VBA it works until the line where I try to insert the search text. So any interaction with the new open search window would throw an error.

Could it be just a matter of a reference that I am not using? See my references below:

[image]

Any help is highly appreciated!

Comment: What error message do you get? Are you sure that after Ctrl+Shift+F6 (`...btn[42]").press`) SAP GUI opens a popup and this popup contains the input field named `SEARCH_BY-MATNR`? (check this by pressing F1 inside SAP GUI popup field "search text", press button "Technical information" and look at the value in field "Screen field")

Comment: Hi Sandra, Thank you for your reply. I'm afraid it does. [link](https://imgur.com/ACaqj0u)

Comment: What error message do you get?

Comment: Error # 619 generated by SAP frontend Server. The control could not be found by id. However, that same code works when I run scripting playback. It's only throwing the error when used in VBA...

Comment: It really means that the field is not there. When you run your VBA, do you really see that the SAP GUI popup opens?

Comment: Yes it does. However, any code that involves interaction with the new open window would throw an error.

Comment: I really can't help except to tell you how to troubleshoot yourself: debug your VBA, inspect the variable `session` (spy), look at the Children until you see the field. Alternatively you may use a tool "SAP_GUI_Script_ScreenRead_Sample.ZIP" attached to the [SAP note 1441550 - SAP GUI scripting: Sample applications](https://launchpad.support.sap.com/#/notes/1441550/E) to inspect the screen fields directly, and you'll get the right field ID. If you don't have access to SAP support, you may use a similar tool named "[Scripting Tracker](https://tracker.stschnell.de/index.htm)", by Stefan Schnell.

Comment: Thanks for the info. But I'm getting the same ID that I was using. However, after further investigation I found that anytime I use  "wnd[X]" where X is other than '0' VBA throws an error. Even though it works fine when I run the recorded script.

Comment: `wnd[0]` is the main window, `wnd[1]` is for a popup at the first level, `wnd[2]` is for a popup at the second level, and so on.

Comment: Thank you Sandra, I kind of know what it means. However, have you ever experience a similar problem in VBA whenever you try to an object with higher window's level than '0'?

Comment: In some cases, a short break has worked wonders for me. For example:                                                                                               ... session.findById("wnd[0]/tbar[1]/btn[42]").press             Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue ("00:00:01")) session.findById("wnd[1]/usr/txtSEARCH_BY-MATNR").text = "53211" ...

Comment: I'm afraid that didn't work for me @ScriptMan...

Comment: What transaction are we talking about?

Comment: I don't understand why VBS works but not VBA, in exactly the same context. I know only one case where both would fail if the popup opens asynchronously (because the popup belongs to a new session, the event GuiApplication.CreateSession should be handled). We can't help because we need a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).